Help identify this TV show with jet flying through barn?
I remember this TV show where, I'm pretty sure, on the opening credits, a small jet crosses some kind of barn whose gate is closing, and turns the plane 90 degrees so that it fits. I'm not 100% sure these are the opening credits or some scene in a chapter. It may even be a movie. Anyhow, here is a drawing of how it looked like:


When did you see it? What language was it in? ... etc. Any little fact you can remember helps.

Sounds like the opening scene of the James Bond movie Octopussy:



(The link should play at the section I mean @1m29s)

